# Careers Stack Overflow - Tag "ruby-on-rails" returns jobs that don't contain the tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Click on the tag "ruby-on-rails" from a job or just go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/ruby-on-rails and you'll see a lot of jobs (969 for me right now), a lot of them not containing the tag. I think that the results are actually just the search result for the "Ruby on Rails" string, using OR.

Comment: I don't get the close vote?...

Comment: @nicael looks like some people on MSE have no clue what Careers is, and think it's just Stack Overflow. Not much we can do, just watch and fix their mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that the implementation also searches the body of the job. We have a lot of employers that don't always use the tag system correctly so this helps to surface jobs that would otherwise not be found. I'm afraid there's not anything that can work around it at the moment, so I'm marking this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

However, we are working on improving job search by providing advanced features that allow you to explicitly specify to only search tags (amongst other things). Expect that in 6-8 weeks...